# How do I tell javascript to verify my information and direct me to another page at the same time through a submit button

Tags: javascript, html

Hey guys I am new to web development. I am currently trying to learn JavaScript.

At the moment I am trying to create a page where when it loads up, the page will ask for the user to input his/her zip code. Now I have a specific zip code that I want the user to input which is 11385. Now, after the user inputs the zipcode I want JavaScript to check if that zipcode is 11385, if it is 11385 I want an alert to pop up and for it to direct me to another page.

I am trying to teach myself coding so I don't really have anyone to ask if you could bear with me. Thank you in advance your help is greatly appreciated.

```html
<form action="c:/users/lui/desktop/index.html" method="post" onsubmit="return ver()">
  <fieldset>
    <legend>zip code Information</legend> <label for="shippingName">Name:</label>
    <input type="text" name="Name" id="shippingName" required><br/>

    <label for="billingzip">Zip code:</label> <input type="text" name="zip" pattern="[0-9]{5}" required><br/>
  </fieldset>

  <input type="submit" value="Verify" />
</form>

<script>
  function ver() {
    var eje = document.getElementById('zip_code');

    if (eje.value == 11385) {
      alert("thank you");
    }
    return true;
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to StackOverflow.

You forgot to give your zip input the id `zip_code`. This is why the DOM query in your `ver` function always resolves to `null`.

As for the redirecting, check the answer of unknown coder, or, for a little more context, the [MDN docs on Window.location](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/location). Your check could look something like this:

```js
if (eje.value == 11385) {
  alert("thank you");
  window.location = "redirect.html";
}
```

Comment: thank you! the zip code validation worked! Now the redirecting part is not working. I tried window.location, window.location.href and even location. When I input my zipcode and click submit, the function runs, I get a thank you alert. But after I click "ok" the page stays the same it does not redirect me to the page I want it to.

Comment: <script>
  function ver(){
  
  var eje=document.getElementById('zip_code');
  var web= "c:/Users/Lui/Desktop/fluidimaging.html";
  
  if(eje.value==11385){
  alert("thank you");
  window.location = web;
  
  }
  }
  </script>

Answer (score 0):

In JS you can redirect using 
window.location.href = 'some url'
that's all you need to add after you validate your input value